# What's the proper way to show money in an UI in Java?

Tags: java, formatting, currency

On the backend I'm storing money values in a Money class which wraps a BigDecimal and sets rounding to be always Half Even with scale 8. All basic operations work fine and behave as expected. But I need to show those values to the user with scale of 2, and that's bringing me rounding errors.

For example, I have these values in the backend:

a = 109.11432
b = 9015.57069
c = 9124.68501

Each one of them is formatted to the pt-BR locale:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(new Locale("pt","BR")));
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
String n = nf.format(valor);
return n;
```

And then I have

a = 109,11
b = 9.015,57
c = 9.124,69

And that's ok, at first. But c should be a + b. With the real values, this is guaranteed, but the rounding gives me a 0.01 error.

What's the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: I don't think you should be storing 109.11432, round it, I mean when you go to the store does the cashier ask you to pay 5,90132$? ;]

Comment: There are a lot of operations done before I get to these results, lots of multiplications, adds, divides, that lead to these values I've shown. If I round each operation, in the end my errors are a lot bigger than 1 cent. I've done it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be doing exactly what you want it to. The way you are storing it, you are storing far beyond 0.01. If that is not your intention, then stop doing it :)

If you want a + b to equal c with 2 decimal places, then you need to round before doing the addition. The solution to your issue depends on the requirements of your application. One common way of storing money is actually with an integer. That way, you cannot store fractions and you could never have the issue you are currently describing.

But it really depends on your requirements. Are you required to do money arithmetic based on 0.01, or on full accuracy and then round the end result? That's a business question, not a technical question.

Comment: sure you can have the same issue - you still need to round at some point.

Comment: No, you can't have the exact same issue because he is adding two stored money values. Adding two stored money values when using an integer can never have 1+7 = 9 which is the exact issue he is having.

Using an integer forces you to make the appropriate decisions of rounding and arithmetic before you store the value.

Comment: I'm required to do money arithmetic based on full accuracy and then round the end result. That's the problem.

Comment: Which thing is the end result? The problem here is now you're saying a+b=c at two decimals--why? If this is only for display purposes then displaying .12 when you're storing .125 is wrong--it's a lie. If you are storing fractional pennies, display that or you will get these weird things. If c is some final answer thing, detect a situation where .4 + .4 = .8 means 0 + 0 = 1 and instead round one up and one down. Anyway... again, you're asking a business question, not a technical one. What are the rules/constraints around these calculations. Once you have those defined, you can implement it.

Comment: I guess you're right, taotree. I need two decimals only for display purposes, so it ends up being a lie, indeed. We've been discussing our requirements around this issue, and hopefully will settle into a solution based on the business needs of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a `NumberFormat` *also* can have a [rounding mode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode)).

But ultimately, no rounding method can fulfill a business requirement like "these values have to add up to this one" without being designed specifically for that case. Round-half-even is designed to avoid a large-scale bias, not single last-decimal errors. So where do you originally get the data from? That's where you have to make sure that the rounding preserves the total.

Is storing the data with 8 fractional digits really a requirement, since you display only 2? I'd also question the assumption that "With the real values, this is guaranteed", since the same thing could happen there, when rounding to 8 digits after whatever calculation produced the values.

Answer (score 0):

If I were writing a money class, I would make it consist of two integer portions - dollars and cents (or reais and centavos, or whatever). That way you never end up with fractional cents. You just have to handle rolling over 100 cents in the addition and subtraction operations.

EDIT:

The comment to my original response has a good point. Another option would be to just store the number of cents, then divide by 100 when you need to display.

Comment: I don't think it's a good way to handle this problem, there will be too many problems implementing all the operations so they work properly. I think it will be too error prone.